# Using event handlers to update SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wpf, xaml

I'm looking for a bit of advice if possible.  I am using event handlers to update a WPF application, it works fine but I was wondering if this was the best way to go?  Would it be better practice to use data binding using XAML?

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info about what you're doing / which event handlers etc.

Comment: I've just started it Purplegoldfish, but so far I am using _TextChanged when a user modifies information on a form type, such as a textbox.  I'm wondering if I am going down the wrong road.

Comment: If you want to adhere to the [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern then using bindings in XAML is the way to go. That way you can define a `DependencyProperty` on the code-behind and react on the property changed event.

Comment: Thanks Xtr, I will start implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would use data binding to do this and the MVVM pattern.

At the most basic you would bind your textbox to a property on your view model, in the setter you could call a method which executes your SQL query. Your View Model class would also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to allow the view model to update the UI if you wanted data to flow both ways.

Although depending on what you're doing you may be better having something that triggers the SQL update rather than every time the text changes. If you have a lot of different fields to update and you use the text changed event you're going to fire off a lot more SQL updates than you need. Maybe a save button or something which detects when changes are finished and makes them all at once would be more efficient?

Comment: In cases where a save button or something similar is not an option you could always define a timer that stops and starts when the text changes. That way the timer would be reset while the user is still typing and will fire the elapsed event of the timer when the specified interval passed. Then you could add the SQL update code to the elapsed event handler. It's not ideal, but could work depending on the situation.

Comment: Interesting ideas guys, I am redeveloping a legacy visual basic / access client information system.  Currently they have a save button that they would press to save any changes made, but I thought I would try and make it more dynamic, so that they didn't lose any changes that they made and then record the changes that are made in a seperate area so that there was a historic trail.